# Is there any way I could change the λ hyperparameter in Yolov5_DeepSort_Pytorch

Tags: python, hyperparameters, yolov5

In the paper 'Simple Online and Realtime Tracking with a Deep Association Metric' ([paper URL](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.07402)), it's reported that when creating a weighted sum, setting λ=0 was a reasonable choice.

Is there any way I could change this hyperparameter in Yolov5_DeepSort_Pytorch?➡([codes URL](https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_DeepSort_Pytorch))

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has not been implemented in the repo yet, as can be seen here: https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_DeepSort_Pytorch/issues/138

Edit 06 Dec 2021:

This has now been implemented. Check:

https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_DeepSort_Pytorch/blob/57f411b3bc7b6012b17a58da4c000186eb1f209e/deep_sort_pytorch/deep_sort/sort/tracker.py#L38